# Instâncias de classes Singleton Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, request, instanciar-objeto

Estou com uma dúvida na seguinte situação:

**Singleton Classe**

```
namespace TesteSingleton
{
    public class Singleton
    {
        private Singleton _singleton;

        public Singleton()
        {
            if (_singleton == null)
                _singleton = new Singleton();
        }

        public int CodigoSingleton
        {
            get
            {
                return _singleton.CodigoSingleton;
            }
            set
            {
                _singleton.CodigoSingleton = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quando é criado essa instância por uma requisição em asp.net core, e na mesmo tempo realizo outra requisição que também usa essa classe, os dados de cada requisição (que serão diferentes) é mantido a integridade de dados? A instância da classe é criada para cara requisição realizada, mesmo que seja feito 2 requisição ao mesmo tempo?

```
namespace Singleton
{
    public class SingletonController : ControllerBase
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var singleton = new Singleton();
            singleton.CodigoSingleton = 10;

            return OK();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como você instancia isso no seu código?

Comment: Editei Virgilio, mas vou estanciar normalmente ela;

Comment: A sua classe não está no padrão Singleton ou não está sendo usado Injeção de Dependencia para tal, por isso cada instância é diferente uma da outra. Se você quiser fazer Singleton precisa utilizar de outra forma! é isso que você deseja fazer?

Comment: Na verdade acabaria não sendo uma classe singleton, mas sim garantir que ela seja instanciada apenas 1 vez em cada requisição feita por 1 usuário. Quase igual uma session sabe? Essa classe em cenário real, gostaria de guardar alguns dados do mobile que mando junto no request, e juto disso manter a integridade dos dados mesmo quando houver requisições simultâneas. Obs: Não gostaria de mexer com session, acha que a forma que estou fazendo resolveria minha situação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente isso é uma classe com padrão `Singleton`:

```
public class Singleton
{
    protected Singleton() { } // não tem instanciação pelo construtor

    private static Singleton _singleton;

    public static Singleton Instance 
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (_singleton == null)
            {
                _singleton = new Singleton();
            }
            return _singleton;
        }
    }       

    public int CodigoSingleton { get; set; }
}
```

***Como usar:***

```
Singleton singleton0 = Singleton.Instance;
Singleton singleton1 = Singleton.Instance; // mesma instância de singleton0
```

---

[Exemplo Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/36KBHo)

```
using System;

class Singleton
{
    protected Singleton() { }
    private static Singleton _singleton;

    public static Singleton Instance 
    {
        get { 
            if (_singleton == null)
            {
                _singleton = new Singleton();
            }
            return _singleton;
        }
    }       

    public int CodigoSingleton { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Singleton singleton0 = Singleton.Instance;
        Singleton singleton1 = Singleton.Instance; // mesma instância de singleton0

        singleton0.CodigoSingleton = 5;
        System.Console.WriteLine(singleton1.CodigoSingleton);       
    }
}
```

***Saída***

```
5
```

Comment: Mas a dúvida é, em requisições simultâneas entre usuários diferentes, eu consigo garantir a integridade em cada requisição? Ou seja, que na 1 requisição seja o valor 1, e na requisição 2 o valor seja 2, conforme criado a nova instancia da classe singleton conforme cada requisição ?

Comment: @NicolaBogar se você configurar a injeção de dependência sim você consegue esse efeito, mas, a sua pergunta não fala sobre isso, ela fala de classes singleton ... realmente muito confusa ... O que você pretende fazer? Só lembrando que o que eu fiz vai depender do ciclo de vida da aplicação

Comment: Vou resumir o que pretendo fazer, por exemplo, para cada requisição quero guardar o id do usuário que está fazendo a requisição, e isso vou utilizar em várias assemblies, nesse caso, não queria estar usando a session, e queria saber se consigo ter a integridade de dados para cada classe singleton criada por requisição, gostaria de saber como o C# gerencia isso.

Comment: @NicolaBogar você precisa utilizar Session, Cookie, ou Identity, ou seja, você está indo pelo caminho errado. Use Identity que além de logar e criar uma sessão lhe fornece a recuperação. Para manter uma identidade plena tem que ser assim.